# orphaned transaction how to find parent

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, lost-transactions

basically a newbie and received mining transactions from a pool in 2013/14. cannot remember which pool. recently pulled out wallet.dat and now have TXs which are not in the mempool with 0 confirmations.  when rebroadcasting says missing parents or missing inputs.  how can i find the parents or inputs.  help will receive btc as reward.

can anyone help please!

Answer (score 1):

The `missing inputs` error can mean two things: the parent transactions do not exist anymore OR the outputs that your transaction is trying to spend are already spent by another transaction.

You can first try looking up the txids of the inputs for your transaction in a block explorer. Those txids are the parent transactions, and if you see the transactions in a block explorer, check to see whether the outputs you are trying to spend are already spent. If they are, then your transaction is actually a double spend and is invalid. There is no way to make it valid nor is there any way to "retrieve the coins" from it.

If you see that the outputs your transaction is trying to spend from are still unspent, or if the transaction that spends them has the same transaction ID as your transaction, then that means that your wallet is not fully synced yet.

If you do not see any of the parent transactions, then there is nothing that you can do. It is impossible to determine the contents of the parent transaction given just its hash. You would need to have the full transaction of each parent transaction, but if you do not have those, then there is nothing that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the parents won't make your TX go through.

You will need the parents and the private key of the sending address (the mining pool in your case) so that you can recreate and sign the transaction with

Comment: how do i find the private key of the sending address or even how to find the sending address?

Comment: The address is in the input (which you don't have). The private key i a owned by the mining pool in your case (which you can't remember)